# What's the suggested workflow for setting up multiple scenes for further rendering?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

#### Context:

I have modeled all the objects I need. It's a mechanical product, which has different parts that attach together.

Now, I want to render different "scenes" such as:

1. Each object separate (for catalog)
2. Objects floating (marketing material)
3. Objects attached together (for showing intended use)

I wanted first to organize all the different positions and camera angles that I need, then after everything is set up, I'd press "Render" **ONCE** and it will render all the different "scenes" I created.

#### Question:

Is there any efficient way of doing this? Is there any optimal workflow for rendering different "scenes"?

#### What came to my mind:

- Step 1: Setup a scene
- Step 2: Save a `.blender` file
- *(repeat for each intended scene)*
- Step 3: Open each `.blender` file
- Step 4: Render one by one.

**Problems encountered in this method:** If I later need to change one composition parameter, I would have to open each `.blender` file to do so. And also I would have to actively go to my computer, open each file and press "render".

Comment: Hi :). I usually do it exactly like this, it offers the most flexibility. Which composition parameters do you need editable? Objects? Materials? Light setup? Compositor?

Comment: Hey @JachymMichal I will have to render everything once with white background, blue background and transparent. Changing that in each `.blender` file seems like a hurdle. That's my thought.

Comment: I understand :). The color changes could be linked through a compositor nodegroup. Blender can also save your render with all 3 backgrounds at once, using *File Output* nodes :)). You still have to manually open each scene though and hit "Render" though.